# Best practise with elasticsearch id

Tags: elasticsearch

With elasticsearch you can define your own id or let elasticsearch apply its own.

What is the best practise for storing ids?

My application is going to have users and each user can have an item, basically, think of this as a blog.

Would the following be acceptable

```
id = user23_post1
```

Or would you use the internal way to manage the ids and create your own id

```
item_id = user23_post1
```

Coming from a relation database background, I have my incremental id hat on, which isn't the way to think when approaching solr or elascticsearch. So I'm looking at what other people have already done and possibly learn from their mistakes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are *not* using Elasticsearch as a datastore, but as a search engine.

This would mean, that ElasticSearch does not *own* any data, it is analogous to a cache layer that has a very fast lookup!

In which case, I wouldn't expect Elasticsearch to hold any IDs, at least not something that is exposed outside. Having ids in sync with the datastore will help trickling atomic and delta updates.

However, elasticsearch can also be used as a NOSQL datastore, in which case, I would have the IDs generated in Elasticsearch.

Comment: Even though I have postgres database for the users, their content is to be stored in ElasticSearch.

Comment: to be indexed. It will need to be searchable.

Comment: Ok, so that's what I meant, by using Elasticsearch as a search engine. I would recommend denormalizing the data, and use the same I'd, so that there is some level of data integrity. Note that, by not being a rdbms system, elasticsearch cannot offer unique constraint like features